# go Mgo session mode change per query

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am initializing my master `*mgo.Session` mode value to `mgo.Monotonic` when I first create a MongoDB connection. I was wondering if anyone has seen any issues if we change the mode to say `mgo.Strong` for the copied session using `masterSession.Copy()`

The reason I am trying to do this is because there are times when I would prefer to read from the primary node to avoid any issues with replica set lag and there are cases where it's okay to rely on read from secondary or replica node.

Would love to know how developers out there handle this similar scenarios
Thanks